# When Git deletes or removes a file where does it go?

Tags: macos, git, atlassian-sourcetree

When Git removes files either through a soft or hard reset - where do these files go? Is there any way to go back to the condition before a mixed reset?

Normally when a file is deleted on an operating system, it goes to a trash can. When files are deleted or removed via Git they seem to go into an ether. Where do these files go?

**I have a stack of new files that weren't added properly and I foolishly ran a mixed reset and now these files are no where to be seen.**

I'm using SourceTree for OS X by the way.

Comment: "Normally when a file is deleted on an o/s it goes to a trash can" --- not "normally" at all actually.

Comment: Ok, "in my limited experience it goes to a trash can". Fixed. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Commit more often, then go back and clean up your commit history later if it bothers you. I always check there are no changes (via `git status -sb`) before doing any sort of reset.

Comment: SourceTree for Windows or OS X? It makes a difference, they don't always have the same features.

Comment: We need more information here. Did you not `git add` or `git commit` the files before they were deleted? If you at least `git add`ed them, then Git keeps a temporary snapshot of the files that you added that is still recoverable (at least until you run `git gc`), probably via something like `git fsck`.

Answer (score 2):

If you did a `--mixed` or `--soft` reset , then the files in your directory would not have gone anywhere because those types of resets do not effect your working tree. With a `--hard` reset the files in your working tree will be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

> When files are deleted or removed via Git they seem to go into an ether. Where do these files go?

When you do a hard reset git will [`unlink(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/unlink) the files.

The data *might* still be there on the file system but there are no guarantees. Please read https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10883 where some recovery tools are mentioned, mostly for ext3.

The git `commit`, `stash` and `branch` commands are often used to save work. Also pay a special attention to the [`reflog`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog) for locating and re-retrieveing runaway leaf changes, especially after a `reset`.